# Gesture Reconizer doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having some trouble to make gestures work. Let me explain:
I got a view that contais a UIImageView for the background and a UIImageView over the background. In this image view over the background, I add some UIViews that contais images and buttons, so that the user can edit. When I'm editing these views when they are over the ImageView, everything works fine. But If I start editing these views over the backgroundView, it doesn't work anymore. Let show some images to help you understanding:

[image: image1]

*Editing the view works fine in this*

[image: image2]

*Don't work*

All three buttons got it own gesture recognizers.
Is this not working because the view is not in the superview anymore? And do I have to add the view to self.view and not to to the imageView to be able to recognize every gesture?

Comment: Views do not respond to touches if they're outside the bounds of their superview, so your supposition about why it isn't working is correct.

Comment: Is there a way to force this views to respond to this gestures in this case? Because I still can move the view, even if it is out of the bound of the image view, but the buttons (close, resize and rotate) doesn't respond anymore

Comment: You can move it out of the superview because the original touch happened inside the superview. If you lift your finger when it's outside the superview, can you move it again? I'm guessing not. As far as I know, the only solution is to add that view to self.view just like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Override the following `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods and make sure you've set the delegates. Sounds like you're bound to see some conflicts which can be avoided using some careful logic in these methods:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

Comment: Hi.I can't see how would this help me, because the gesture methods are never fired when the view is out of the bounds of the image view. Can you explain it?